# Do above counter bowl sinks require special cabinets?

Tags: bathroom, sink

I am currently renovating a bathroom.  In the process, I'll be replacing the ugly 1970s vanity with a new craftsman style cabinet, solid surface countertop, and two above counter glass bowl sinks.  However, I am getting a bit concerned about the sink height, as the sink will no longer be set into the vanity.  How is this typically dealt with?  Standard height cabinets?  Special cabinets that are lower/designed for these sinks?  Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the vanity is so small that it just supports the bowl but with no usable countertop, then the vanity is often lower than standard by 8" or so.

But if there is usable space on the counter than it's more important to have that work space (shave space?) at a comfortable height than it is to have the top of the sink at a standard height.

Answer (score 0):

They're typically used on standard height cabinets, but have the effect of making the bowl higher. Here's another question that deals with [bathroom vanity height](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/569/bathroom-vanity-height).

Answer (score 0):

Take into consideration the expected users of the bathroom (not just current but future).

It sounds like this is probably your master and so will be focused on adults, so the raised height should be fine.

If this is a common area bathroom or connected to a secondary bedroom, even if you don't have children, you want to consider visitors and future re-sale so keeping the sink level at standard height would be best.